# Нужен исходник UDP терминала написанный на Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, udp

Доброго всем времени суток.
4й день изучаю Java, пока что больше вопросов, чем понимания.

Может есть у кого исходник UDP терминала написанного на Android Studio?
Например, TermUDP v1.0 по функционалу даже больше, чем мне нужно, но где найти исходник в качестве примера для старта?

Не хватает знаний совместить в рабочий проект куски кодов с примерами UDP-клиента и сервера, которые есть в сети.

Comment: такого хватит http://msdalp.github.io/2014/03/09/Udp-on-Android/ или нет?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вчера на этот пример наткнулся как раз, значит иду в правильном направлении=)!